# Possible issue between DELETE and INSERT in MySQL with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, race-condition

I am not entirely sure this is possible, so would like clarification if it is and if so what is the way forward (to prevent or if not possible to mitigate).

I have a PHP script which allows user submitted data (which does an INSERT INTO) and another PHP script (different file) which allows the deletion of said data (which does a DELETE FROM), now lets say I was deleting stuff and there happens to be someone submitting some stuff at the same time - could this lead to data being overlooked (remaining in that table)?

I have searched and come across stuff relating to race conditions - unsure if this is exactly what the above issue would be classed as?

If it helps to put the above into the context, the user has the ability to submit replies (posts) to a topic (which does an INSERT INTO forum_posts WHERE topic_id = ?) and I have the ability to delete the topic (which should hopefully delete all attached posts) i.e. DELETE FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id = ? and then DELETE FROM forum_posts WHERE topic_id = ?, if when doing the deletion a user was to somehow be able to post a reply to the topic, then this could cause issues (as we have a post which exists with no topic!).

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you can have a race condition here - your test for row existence happens to occur in one process exactly between a test and an operation in another. You can lock the tables to prevent this from happening, and use foreign key constraints to prevent database corruption in general.

Comment: Or maybe use something called a _semaphore_ - a flag (stored wherever, i.e. in database) that controls and is supposed to prevent race conditions. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_%28programming%29.

Comment: @Kleskowy Thanks for this, don't suppose you have any kind of example coding to get me started, the wikipedia link covers the topic but not on how to introduce it in to PHP/MySQL?

Comment: Would adding an IF within the INSERT INTO query to check if topic_id exists IN forum_topics, resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what transactions are made for.
For example (pseudo-code)

```
$db->beginTransaction();

// A set of queries; if one fails, an exception should be thrown
$db->query('first query');
$db->query('second query');
$db->query('third query');

// If we arrive here, it means that no exception was thrown
// i.e. no query has failed, and we can commit the transaction
$db->commit();
```

When you do the `commit` all 3 transactions are done simultaneously w/o delay, and will not be interrupted by some other user deleting something

Comment: Thanks @Oleg, I understand you don't know the ins and outs of my project, but I have added additional info to put my question into context (see above) - do you think the transactions would be more appropriate on the PHP script for deletion or on the PHP script for insertion, or both? Will definitely do more research on this!

Comment: This will not work, as it isn't a single call that's performing all queries. If I understand it correctly the OP is talking about the case that user A inserts, and user B deletes at the same time.

Comment: @giorgio That is exactly what I am asking!

Comment: Please explain. Say, a record doesn't exist. What if one user deletes and old record and another user adds  a new record? What's wrong with it? Please explain your concern

Comment: @OlegDubas I have further updated my question (see above) to elaborate. :)

Comment: The question refers to race conditions between *different* users, as @giorgio says. Transactions do not apply here.